# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API Project cannot connect SignalR via postman

Tags: c#, postman, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a simple SignalR implementation following [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_pRk7PwkpY&t=252s). I added its dependency with `builder.Services.AddSignalR();` in my `Program.cs` class. Then added Map into my CustomHub with this : `app.MapHub<PublicChatHub>("public-chat");`

Here My Hub Class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace WebAPI.SignalR;

public sealed class PublicChatHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{Context.ConnectionId} connected.");
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{Context.ConnectionId} disconnected.");
    }
}
```

When i try to call `wss://localhost:7142/public-chat` via postman connecting socket successfully but code not hitting my breakpoint on `OnConnectedAsync()`.

Sending this message after connect :

```
{
   "protocol": "json,
   "version": 1
}�
```

� is 0x1E ascii.

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:7142/public-chat? If you code a simple client with HTML, you can test your code more easily.

Comment: `FetchHttpClient.ts:102 Fetch API cannot load localhost:7142/public-chat/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.` on  `localhost:7142/public-chat` fetch.



and 

 `http://localhost:7142/public-chat/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on `http://localhost:7142/public-chat` fetch.

Comment: Can you share your launchSettings.json file with us

Comment: My iisSettings section same as urs. Just running on different port.
But usually i run my application via "profiles" section.
`     "LoginSampleAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7142",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Postman Client

For my main question, which i cannot access my hub via `postman` with web socket, i figured out my � is not actually 0x1E ascii or something like it. On [this link](https://trailheadtechnology.com/using-postman-with-signalr-websockets-development/) i found a body template which similiar to mine, but the end character is different.

Changed my message body with this:

```
{"protocol":"json","version":1}
```

(should be escape character at end, cannot post it but you can find on link at top)

and my `wss://localhost:7142/public-chat` started response.

---

### JS Client

Thanks to fatih, helped to solve my js client, running with `Live Server` vscode extension problem to solve, which was CORS.
Solved it with use `app.Cors();` middleware as Services, which is

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
    configure => configure.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5500") // your client 
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
);
});
```

and use policy as middleware:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.MapHub<PublicChatHub>("/public-chat");
```

For js client which running with `Live Server` extension my codes are :

```
 let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("https://localhost:7142/public-chat") // your server (check out http or https request)
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

connection.start().then(function () {
console.log("connected");
}).catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
console.log("Message received: " + message);
});
```

And calling it with simple html page.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/signalr@latest/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

After all, both my client; postmand and js run success.

Comment: I cannot post escape character, check out link for template.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share with you a basic signalR API. I tested this and it is work at my local. You can try like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                );
        });

        builder.Services.AddSignalR();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapHub<ExampleHub>("/exampleHub");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ExampleHub : Hub
{
  
    public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
       //debug
        
    }
    public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        
    }
}
```

iisSettings in launchSettings.json is like this:

```
 "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3200",
  "sslPort": 0
  }
},
```

If you can not connect this project, probably your client has a problem.

connection url: "http://localhost:3200/exampleHub"

Comment: Thanks! When i created different backend application it worked. I will check out my main project codes again. If i get any point i will inform. Also as you said, in video he opening socket on postman, however i cannot. I could connect via javascript client.

Comment: Also for note, i used cors on `app` section (as missdeware). It was giving CORS error on client side, which i'm using pure html, js and running on `Live Server` extension on vscode. Moved CORS section to services, added  `AllowCredentials()` into my policy (otherwise client kept giving cors error). After all it worked.

Comment: But i still cannot figure out, why i cannot make a web socket call into my hub just like video, which i shared on my question. Your answer helped me to solve my js client CORS problem.